# Inset by a specific measurement

Tags: modeling

I would like to be able to inset a face by exactly 1mm so I can easily extrude out 1mm walls. However, the only value that seems related is called 'thickness', which starts at 0 and then goes to a seemingly arbitrary value with no relation to the actual thickness of the inset it is creating.
Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your [scene units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXRpx.png) (*Properties > Scene Properties > Units*) are set to *Metric*, there should be a direct relationship between the value you want in mm and *Thickness*. The other main option that has a direct effect on the result is *Offset Even*. When on, your walls would have a thickness of 1mm; when off, the corner edge would have a length of 1mm instead:

[image]

Be aware that *Scale* of the object does not affect the values shown here until it's applied. A plane of 2m with a scale of 2 would still show these same numbers in Edit mode, but they would double when the scale is applied.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was a combination of not applying scale and having Offset Even turned off that made it so I couldn't find a relationship between the thickness parameter and actual thickness. Now it works as expected!

Comment: @Kuboå thanks for the catch I did something similar to the user (didn't apply scale till after the fact) the numbers I used with the scale of (3.5) just so happen to work out...strange.

https://i.imgur.com/obePxyF.png